# How to change useragent-string in runtime chromedriver selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, user-agent

I am developing something that want me to change the useragent.
In start I supply user agent as... (to chromedriver)

```
options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25");
```

But then I want to change it to Windows useragent, or just remove this useragent.

How can I achieve this programatically in Selenium Java.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, you can't change the **useragent** of an active *Browsing Session* once you configure the *WebDriver* instance through an instance of *ChromeOptions* and **addArguments** attribute and start an active *Browsing Session*.

Even if you are able to extract the `Session ID`, `Cookies`, `User Agent` and other *Session Attributes* from the active *Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change/edit those attributes as a HOOK to the *WebDriver*.

To change the *User Agent* you have to re-configure the *WebDriver* instance and initiate a new *Browsing Session*.

Comment: ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return navigator.userAgent");
This is a way to get the useragent, can't we change it through this?

Answer (score 2):

As @Debanjan said You can't change user-agent in runtime, but did You try using ModifyHeader plugin, You can setup it to change user-agent but not at already instantiated driver. You can setup during webDriver instantiation and also try with ChromeOptions.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("src/main/resources/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj.crx"));

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

or

```
ChromeOptions chrome = new ChromeOptions();
chrome.addArguments("user-agent=YOUR_USER_AGENT");
```